# Import/Include config Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

Is it possible to store config such as `config['webapp2_extras.API']` in a different file, and then include it in an other?

Pseudocode:

```
# config.py
config['webapp2_extras.API'] = {
  'option' : value,
}

# frontcontroller.py
webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/',handler='MainHandler')
  ], config={{CONFIG_FROM_CONFIG.PY}})
```

I would really like to be able to store my config(s) elsewhere than my frontcontroller!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing config in frontcontroller.py? For example

```
# config.py
config['webapp2_extras.API'] = {
  'option' : value,
}

# frontcontroller.py
import config

webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/',handler='MainHandler')
  ], config=config)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try while putting config in the same folder as frontcaller.py

```
# config.py
config['webapp2_extras.API'] = {
  'option' : value,
}

# frontcontroller.py
from . import config

webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/',handler='MainHandler')
  ], config=config.config)
```